# Why does netplan overwrite ip route command settings?

Tags: 18.04, netplan

I'm having this really frustrating problem. I have multiple NICs with WAN access and need to switch the default route between them.

This can easily be done using the ip route replace default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno2 command but I noticed that netplan after a minute or two remove the ip route rule.

I know ip route commands don't survive a reboot but I'm not rebooting. Useful Netplan documentation is pretty non existent so I have no clue why this is happening or what can be done to avoid it.

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: false
            optional: true
            addresses: [192.168.0.100/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.0.1]
        eno2:
            dhcp4: false
            optional: true
            addresses: [192.168.100.100]
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.100.1]
    version: 2
```

When I run `ip route replace default via 192.168.100.1 dev eno2` then check with route -n the default route has changed. If I wait a couple of minutes the default route is now gone.

I also tried setting no default gateway for eno1 and the use `ip route add default` but this has the same problem. The default route shows up for a minute or so and then gets removed.

Comment: I really hate netplan.io so I dug into this a bit.  It looks like netplan.io spits out configs into `/run/systemd/network/` that are then consumed by systemd-networkd.  Presumably systemd-networkd is the daemon that is changing your settings.

I can't find anything that indicates systemd-networkd periodically reapplies settings; is it possible your network connection is iffy and is losing link?

Comment: I'm testing with a VM so that's not it. I think I found the problem. One one of my VM's I set up two different subnets as per my original post and on this VM the route isn't resetting. However another device I was testing with, the actual hardware I will be using, wasn't hooked up to two different subnets. Instead both NICs were on the same subnet because I was busy and didn't want to change my switch and router config. Seems that was the problem. For whatever reason any route you set with ip route will be removed after a minute or so if both NICs are on the same subnet.